# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS - The icon in "favorites" on the left isn't showing properly (Bluej)

Tags: java, icons, .desktop, favorites

So it's just a simple question because I really don't like the aesthetic of it (even though the software is working just fine), I installed Bluej for java and added it to my favorites on the left of the screen but instead of seeing the logo of Bluej, a blue jay, I get a grey box with a red circle inside (so like a forbidden sign). It also shows that when I just open Bluej and it's not in my favorites.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you very much

Comment: can you mention our OS by editing your Question please?

Comment: How did you installed Bluej. (Assuming you're running Ubuntu) If you installed it downloading the `BlueJ-linux-420.deb`, sometimes this happens because the icon pack you are using does not support that specific app.

Comment: I edited the title. And yes I used the .deb, is there really no solution?

Comment: You can fix the problem by following thefirst answer here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251172/active-application-icon-not-shown-on-dock