# Active application icon not shown on dock

Tags: 20.04, icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I have got some applications such as **KColorChooser**, **KBreakOut**, **MadView3D** which are not showing any application icon on the dock when they are active. Only a square with no icon is shown. Also, When I hover over them, instead of the application name, **unknown** is shown.
[image]

I am using Gnome as my desktop environment on Ubuntu 20.04. Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have solved the problem with the help of this video: https://youtu.be/xZ_M3Q-U-J0.

**Here is the summary:**
Gnome (and any other Desktop) identify instances of an application and keeps track of them with the WM_CLASS property.
Some of the KDE applications do not provide a WM_CLASS property within them and due to this missing WM_CLASS property, Gnome cannot keep track of the applications and therefore cannot associate the icons with them. Every time a new instance of that same app is created, it shows a new element on the dock.
This problem also occurs in KDE plasma: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=160452

**Solution:**

- Open the application which behaves this way.
- Open up a terminal and issue the command `xprop WM_CLASS`. The mouse cursor will change to a + symbol. Click on that application with the + shaped cursor. The WM_CLASS string will be printed out on the terminal.
  [image]
- Copy the `.desktop` file of that application from `/usr/share/applications/` folder to your local directory `~/.local/share/applications/` folder. For me, it was named **org.kde.kcolorchooser.desktop**.
  **Do not modify the original file, because it will get replaced whenever the application is updated**.
- Open the file in a text editor and add the line `StartupWMClass=<WM_CLASS>` where <WM_CLASS> should be replaced by the string you got from the above command. For me, it was `StartupWMClass=kcolorchooser`.
- Save the file and enjoy! The problem will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issues with the Ubuntu taskbar icons, please run this commands to get rid of taskbar icon missing problem.

```
sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*

sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```